# Solving a Word Problem relating to factorisation

Tags: analysis, number-theory

The $\text{Ionof}$ (Integer on number of factors) of an integer is the integer divided by the number of factors it has. For example, $18$ has $6$ factors so $\text{Ionof}(18) = \frac{18}{6} = 3$, and $27$ has $4$ factors so $\text{Ionof}(27) = \frac{27}{4} = 6.75$.

a) Find $\text{Ionof}(36)$

b) Explain why $\text{Ionof}(pq)$ is not an integer if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

c) If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, find all numbers of the form $(pq)^4$ whose $\text{Ionof}$ is an integer.

d) Show that the square of any prime number is the $\text{Ionof}$ of some integer.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format your questions/answers. Also, people here on MSE appreciate seeing what you have tried.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti You are back!

Answer (score 3):

Okay. I'll leave the problem a) for you.

For the second one. Observe the $pq$ has 4 distinct factors, namely $(1, p, q, pq)$. Also, observe that $p$ and $q$ are **distinct** prime i.e. that both of them can't be $2$. So, since all other prime numbers are odd, $pq$ isn't a multiple of $4$ which is the number of prime factors. Hence, $\text{Ionof}(pq)$ isn't an integer.

Comment: I will leave it as a comment here. The ionof of a number whose factorisation is $2^a3^b5^c... $ is $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)... $ by combinatorics. Show that $p^2$,where $p$ is a prime, can be written in this form

Comment: for c), there actually are possible combinations. i.e. 3 and 5, $(3.5)^4 = 50625.       \frac{50625}{25} = 2025.$