# Numbers $m = pq^4$ ($p,q$ are distinct primes) for which $m$ divided by the number of its factors is an integer

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The $\operatorname{Ionof}$ (Integer on number of factors) of an integer is the integer divided by the number of factors it has. For example, $18$ has $6$ factors so $\operatorname{Ionof}(18) = \frac{18}{6} = 3$, and $27$ has $4$ factors so $\smash{\operatorname{Ionof}(27) = \frac{27}{4} = 6.75}$.

This has been asked here --- [Solving a Word Problem relating to factorisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760884/solving-a-word-problem-relating-to-factorisation) --- but it was not given context.

> If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, find all numbers of the form $pq^4$ whose $\operatorname{Ionof}$ is an integer.

I have tried substituting $p$ and $q$ for real numbers, but have not seen any consistent pattern.

I am really at a loss here. Any hints would be helpful, and also let me know if I need to reword, or provide more context.

Comment: You might also want to refer to this question: [Interesting and unusual word problem with prime numbers and factors](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798956/interesting-and-unusual-word-problem-with-prime-numbers-and-factors/1799017#1799017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$pq^4$ has $10$ factors: $1, p, q, q^2, q^3, q^4, pq, pq^2, pq^3, pq^4$. This means that for Ionof$(pq^4)$ to be an integer, $pq^4$ must be divisible by $10$. Then $p$ and $q$ must multiple to a factor of $10$. The only prime numbers which serve this are $5$ and $2$. Therefore $p=2, q=5$, or $p=5, q=2$.

Comment: Wait where did x and y come into play?

Comment: @SuperNinja741DoesGaming Oops, edited.

Comment: @anonymous You still have plenty of $x$ and $y$s in your answer...

Comment: @ErickWong There we go! I'm blind...that should be good?

Comment: @anonymous Almost... the factor $pq^2$ appears twice in the list, meaning another factor is missing :).

Comment: @ErickWong Oh dear I really am so hopeless...Now is that fine!!!?!?!?

Comment: @anonymous Looks fine :).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $n \mid pq^4$, then the prime factorization of $n$ contains only factors of $p$ and $q$ (no more than one of the former and four of the latter). How many such numbers are there?

Comment: What does the line between n and pq mean?

Comment: It means that $n$ divides $pq^4$, that is, that $n$ is a factor of $p q^4$.

Comment: I have rolled back an erroneous edit to my answer.